# JSON Parse Facebook comments Google Sheets

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, google-sheets-api

I can successfully get the comments from Facebook insights in my Google sheet via URLFetch.

I then try to parse the response into a variable named result.

var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

The result of the URL fetch is below:

```
{
   "created_time": "2017-04-16T11:00:10+0000",
   "message": "A historic vote on the powers of Turkey's president is under way.",
   "actions": [
      {
         "name": "Share",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews/posts/10154586714572217"
      }
   ],
   "application": {
      "category": "Business",
      "link": "http://socialflow.com/",
      "name": "SocialFlow",
      "namespace": "socialflowapp",
      "id": "128869720483178"
   },
   "caption": "bbc.co.uk",
   "comments": {
      "data": [
         {
            "created_time": "2017-04-16T11:01:40+0000",
            "from": {
               "name": "xxx",
               "id": "xxx"
            },
            "message": "We are not divided.. ! This is just an election of the system. Stop  brainwashing you idiots!",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 156,
            "user_likes": false,
            "id": "10154586714572217_10154586716852217"
         },
```

If I try to select the 'caption' using result.caption it returns the caption as required. However what I really want is the message of each comment.

I have tried result.comments.message, however have come unstuck. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Cheers

Matt

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Apologies - new to StackOverflow but thank you for the advice. FYI, I have managed to solve this problem now :)